# JS Equals values from strings

Tags: javascript, string, variables, var

Hello I need to compare two string values and if any math I want to outputs their values. I got this code.

This give me result of `$values2` and `$hrefs2` :

671,673,676

672,671,670,673,676,675,667,666,674

And I wanna check if any a single value of `$hrefs2` value equals value of `$values2`

After that I wanna change background of color of these classes `document.getElementsByClassName("golden");`

Thanks for any help

```js
// divide string to 3 letters and comma, 3 letters and comm...
function formatNumber (num) {
      return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}


// output values from golden classes
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("golden");
var values = '';
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    values += elements[i].innerText;
}
var values2 = formatNumber(values);
document.write(values2); // output
document.write('<br>');


// output values from hrefo classes
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("hrefo");
var hrefs = '';
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    hrefs += elements[i].href.slice(-3);
 
}
var hrefs2 = formatNumber(hrefs);
document.write(hrefs2); //output
```

Comment: please provide fiddle if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this to see if hrefs2 contains any number from values2:

```
var values2 = '671,673,676';
var values = values2.split(",");

var hrefs2 = '672,671,670,673,676,675,667,666,674';
var hrefs = hrefs2.split(",");

for( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if( hrefs2.indexOf(values[i] ) > -1 ){
       console.log( 'hrefs2 contains number ' + (values[i]) );
    }
}
```

Im not sure what you mean by "After that I wanna change background of color of these classe"? Do you want to create an RGB-background value from the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Thats working thank You so much!. Im sorry for didnt make it clear about background color. So I have Your piece of script.

```js
// output of equals values from two strings
for( var i = 0; i < values3.length; i++){
    if( hrefs2.indexOf(values3[i] ) > -1 ){
       console.log( 'hrefs3 contains number ' + (values3[i]) );
       document.write('<br>');
       document.write(values3[i]); // output 671 673 676
    }
}
```

In site code i got lines like

```
<tr><td>
<a class="hrefo" href="?page=view&amp;id=671">Server1</a>
<a class="hrefo" href="?page=view&amp;id=686">Server2</a>
...
</tr></td>
```

I wanna make that if value of values3[i] equals for instance id=671 then make  background-color red,  where is located id=671

like this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_contains

or another way to achieve that is : if href contains number of values3[i] then give class with background-color: red; to two markup up thats mean a->td>tr and whole row will be red like this [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/VrPdF/5/)